# IEEE 802.15.4/ZigBee packet structure

Tags: zigbee, ieee

Is there a "header label frame" in the structure of IEEE 802.15.4/ZigBee packets?

I understand the basic packet structure from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure) documentation.

so is there such a "header label frame" or "frame label header" in IEEE 802.15.4/ZigBee?

Answer (score 0):

No. ZigBee is designed for short-range communication. It is not based upon IP (Internet Protocol), which was designed for global communication.

Comment: I see the difference but is there such a thing as "header label frame" or "frame label header" in IEEE 802.15.4/ZigBee? - I'm putting the IP example as reference